# Is there a way to attach file with outlook's URL scheme?

Tags: ios, outlook, url-scheme, swift5

I'm creating an ios application that opens the outlook app and attaches file. I can open the outlook app via this URL scheme 
`ms-outlook://compose?to=joe@example.com&subject=Hello&body=Hello` but do not know how to attach file. Is there a way to attach the file from the URL scheme? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Nice thought, but this is not possible.

Comment: thank for reply. @shim sorry, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: The comment I was replying to has been removed. I have deleted my comment. I will delete this comment soon as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to specify an attachment using a URL scheme or the [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v%3Dvs.85)) protocol.